# How to mix windows from different Remote Desktop servers on the same client's screen?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, copy-paste

I'm in front of a thin client capable of running `mstsc.exe`, which I use to connect to a couple of remote systems.

Each individual RDP-session works fine, but each creates a full Windows desktop *of its own* -- application windows running in the different sessions can not interact and aren't even aware of each other.

Even the copy-pasting from one such desktop into another is impossible (yes, the "Clipboard" checkbox in `mstsc.exe` is enabled).

I'd like to be able to mix individual applications from different systems on the same desktop instead -- the way one can mix X11-clients from multiple servers connecting to the same X11-server.

I seem to recall the Remote Desktop Protocol allowing for this, but I can't figure out, how to do it...

*Update*: using the [remoteapplication-method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50759333/1747834) I can invoke an individual application on a remote server instead of the default shell. The application (tested with firefox) comes up as its own window and makes no attempt to replace the local desktop with itself. Is there, perhaps, some alternative to Windows default shell, that would behave the way I want it to?

Comment: I am not aware of any RDP solution that would allow individual RDP sessions to interact with one another.  Typical the only integration is between the host and the RDP session.

Comment: Well, Ok, they don't have to "interact" -- beyond copy/pasting -- but the applications running in each session should just share the desktop, rather than be themselves confined to the bigger "RDP-session" window...

Comment: Have you looked at RemoteApp (part of RDS)? It allows the user to "stream" an application from a remote computer and make it look as if it is running locally. More details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Services#RemoteApp

Comment: @cdavid, not only have I looked at RemoteApp, I mention this in my question. Trouble is, I can only invoke _one_ application this way...